# How to delete a file from a list of files which is taken from a specified path in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit

I got the files from the Application.persistentDataPath and showed it into a list.Each name in the list contains a delete button.When I click the delete button the specified file need to be deleted.The below code is not working.

```
public void ListMap()
{
    panellist.SetActive(true);
    string mainpath = Application.persistentDataPath;
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(mainpath);
   // FileInfo[] info = dir.GetFiles("*.json");


    info = dir.GetFiles("*.json");

    int icopy=0;
    for(int i = 1;i<=info.Length;i++)
    {
         lisobj = Instantiate(prefabpanellist);

            lisobj.transform.SetParent(Parentcontent);
            number.text = i.ToString();
            mapnamedb.text =info[i-1].Name;
             icopy = i;
        Debug.Log("ivalue forloop = " + icopy);
        var button = lisobj.GetComponentInChildren<Button>();
        Debug.Log("Button name = "+button.name);
        if (button != null)
        {
            button.onClick.AddListener(() => Deleteinformation(icopy));
        }

    }



}

public void Deleteinformation(int ivalue)
{
    Debug.Log("ivalue is = " + ivalue);
    string mainpath = Application.persistentDataPath;
   // File.Delete(mainpath + info[ivalue-1]);
    // Debug.Log("ivalue is = "+ivalue);
    File.Delete(mainpath + info[ivalue - 1]);

}
```

The errors are -
1)When I click the different buttons it is trying to delete the same file-Modeldetails1.json

2) Could not find a part of the path "/Users/ar/Library/Application Support/Systica/Mapping/Users/ar/Library/Application Support/Systi/Mapping/Modeldetails1.json".

[image: Delete Button]

Comment: "The below code is not working." Please explain what "not working" means here. Are you getting an error? does the wrong one get deleted?

Comment: @remy_rm first of all the ivalue is not getting printed...The file is still there in the path

Comment: I think this might be a closure issue. try creating a copy of `i` inside your loop, and use this value to pass to `Deleteinformation` instead. `int iCopy = i; delbutton.OnClick.AddListener(() =>Deleteinformation(iCopy));`

Comment: Its is not working...How can we check if a Listener is added?I tried checking on the instantiated object and in the delete button the Onclick is empty

Comment: Where is`delbutton` set? As it is right now you're assigning multiple listeners to the same instance of `delbutton`

Comment: I have added a button in public and dragged and dropped from the prefab which is getting instantiated.

Comment: you need to create many buttons responsible for deleting the single file, attach listeners to those dynamically created buttons

Comment: Are you sure its adding the path deliminator between the persistant data path and the file name when you come to do the actual delete?

Comment: @BugFinder I have added the line Debug.Log("ivalue is = "+ivalue); at the start of the Deleteinformation(int ivalue function)....still it is not printing.So the Listener is not getting added to it I believe

Comment: So you're assigning like 30 listeners to the del button and when it clicks its going to try do all of them....  You show on the screen different buttons, so you need to pick the button for that line not 1 button.

Comment: @BugFinder So I should create and add script to the button

Comment: Create and add the appropriate listener

Comment: @BugFinder I did not understand...any examples....This part is always confusing for me

Comment: Well how did you get the screen print?? You need 1 button per line like the screen print and to assign that button a listener which calls the delete for that line..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191432/discussion-between-zyonneo-and-bugfinder).

Comment: @BugFinder I did not print anything on the screen...

Comment: @zyonneo then where did your picture come from, thats known as a screenprint.

Comment: @BugFinder I am adding listener function in the for loop.I removed that script. I have added the following script to the button prefab in a new script in the Add component.But then how will I know which button is clicked.  .......................                                      void Deleteinformation(int ivalue)
    {
        Debug.Log("ivalue is = " + ivalue);
        string mainpath = Application.persistentDataPath;
        File.Delete(mainpath + WorldMapManager.info[ivalue-1]);
       // Debug.Log("ivalue is = "+ivalue);

    }

Comment: Because each button would be unique, eg the one at the end of the line (which you arent showing how you made, or using in your code) .. it would be specific to each line

Comment: @BugFinder updated code and description...

Comment: I guess you didnt read that getfiles returns the directiory, so you didnt need to add it again.... (this should be obvious from the name)

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
File.Delete(Path.Combine(mainpath, info[ivalue-1]));
```

Comment: but info[ivalue-1] is a gameobject not a string